# Trying to use a composer package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Im using Laravel 5.8.
Im trying to use the following package 
https://packagist.org/packages/s1lentium/iptools

To install it i have run:

composer require s1lentium/iptools

Confirmed the require line is in the composer.json
        "s1lentium/iptools": "^1.1"

and that the package is in "vendor/s1lentium/iptools/"

How can i reference it in the code (controller or even in a view)??
When I try to use the IP class Laravel cannot find it.

I've researched a lot and but without success. Hope anyone can lead me to the correct step.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you run `composer dumpautoload`, then you *should* be able to use it as shown on their page. You may need to add a `use` line at the top of the file using the library's full namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload`

You must call the IP class with `\IPTools\IP`, or `use` it:

```php
use IPTools\IP;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had already ran the "composer dump-autoload" but I didnt know which name use in the "use". Probably a stupid question: how do you know it was "IPTools\IP" ?

Comment: I look through `composer.json` file on github repo, and the namespace for the package is `IPTools`. The class you want is `IP`. So, it is `IPTools\IP`.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that i can help you :)